# Redshift grant access to tables in schema using subselect

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to grant access to all tables in a schema but use a selection condition to include a large number of schemas based on schema name.

I've tried the following and some variations of it, but it does not work.
The GRANT syntax does not allow this, but is it possible to achieve this in SQL another way?

```
-- This is syntactically incorrect but I want it to work
grant select on all tables in schema 
where schema_name in 
  (select schema_name 
   from svv_all_schemas 
   where schema_name like '%sales%')
to group my_group;
```

the following is legal syntax but does not allow the "where like ..." which is what I am after:

```
-- Works but requires manual intervention
grant select on all tables in schema 
  my_sales_schema, my_other_sales_schema, another_sales_schema
to group my_group;
```

I'm thinking an elaborate stored procedure could do this by stashing intermediate datasets, but that seems rather like overkill, can't we use subselects or other SQL to do this up in the SQL engine?
Off the top of my head, we could generate the GRANT statements too, but hopefully there is a simpler way?

Comment: They just introduced this in the last patch release, might make things easier for u, like u don’t need to worry about individual new tables etc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_scoped-permissions.html